# wxpython wx.GetBackgroundColour doesn't work properly

Tags: wxpython

I noticed something weird in wxpython.
test the following code

```
class test(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1 "test")
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(250, 250, 250))
        panel2 = wx.Panel(panel, -1, (50, 50))
        print panel2.GetBackgroundColour()
```

this returns something like 232 232 232 255 when it should be 250 250 250 255. it actually applies to most widgets not just panels e.g. buttons and static texts aswell? any possible explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you have two panels here. You only set the first panel's color and then you print the background color of the second panel. That's probably why they're different...

Comment: I think he was expecting the background colour to be inherited from the parent panel like it appears visually on other controls.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not how it works in wxPython. Each widget has it's own default color in most cases

Comment: Is wxPython not simply a binding onto the C++ implementation?  I'm basing this on the C++ code for wx where the situation regarding widget backgrounds is complicated, especially if themed backgrounds are thrown into the mix (e.g. wxNotebook on Windows).

Comment: It depends on the type of the widget, some will inherit the colors from the parent some will not. As you say it is also complicated by themes and other platform specifics, and has also changed over time.  I always find that the best approach is to explicitly set the colors myself (if I want non-defaults) instead of relying on the inheritance.